# Add integers as strings to a variable bash

Tags: string, bash, int

I want to output a string by adding random integer to a variable to create the string. Bash however, just adds the numbers together.

```
#!/bin/bash
b=""
for ((x=1; x<=3; x++))
do
 number=$RANDOM
 let number%=9
 let b+=$number
done
echo ${b}
```

Say every random number is 1, the script will output 3 instead of 111.
How do I achieve the desired result of 111?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are several possibilities to achieve your desired behavior. Let's first examine what you've done:

```
let b+=$number
```

Running `help let`:

```
let: let ARGUMENT...
    Evaluate arithmetic expressions.
```

That explains why `let b+=$number` performs an integer addition (`1`, `2`, `3`) of `$number` to `b` instead of string concatenation.

Simply remove `let` and the desired behavior `1`, `11`, `111` will occur.

The other method to perform string concatenation:

```
b="$b$number"
```

Yes, simply "let `b` become the result of concatenating `b` and `number`.

As a side note, `b=""` is equivalent to `b=` as `""` is expanded to an empty string. Module operation on a variable can be done with arithmetic expansion: `number=$((RANDOM%9))`.

Comment: You can also do arithmetic expansion like this: `((number = RANDOM % 9))`