# How to read numbers into variables from string

Tags: linux, bash, unix, console

I have strings that look like this:

```
user@pc: $ example="bla bla bla (m=100, number of steps=1.05)"
```

How can I read the values 100 and 1.05 into two variables that I can use them afterwards?

```
user@pc: $ echo $A
100
user@pc: $ echo $B
1.05
```

Comment: [Add integers as strings to a variable bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10474250/608639), [In BASH convert a string with . in float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34286348/608639), [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/56041), [Argument string to integer in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232384/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an extra tool like `grep` to extract numbers first:

```
NUMS=($(grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' <<<"${example}"))
A=${NUMS[0]}
B=${NUMS[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with bash

```
example="bla bla bla (m=100, number of steps=1.05)"
var=(${example//[^0-9 \.]})
for i in ${var[@]};do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: Not quite effective in certain cases: `example="123aaa456bbb789`